# Filled tabs design in Android

Tags: android, tabs

I need to make a tab section in my app, it will only have two tabs.
Exploring several solutions from other applications, I came with this (among others):

[image]

However, it seems to be more of an iOS design, would you discourage this type of tabs on Android from a consistency perspective?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but as an Android user it took me a bit of time to figure out where the tabs even were. I even opened the image in a new tab thinking that maybe its only showing part of a larger image and the tabs were on the bottom. I definitely wouldn't recommend doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you added your app name in the header with the help and add icons, those two tabs could move down and become 'traditional' tabs.

A segment bar control also might be an option to solve this. See: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment

The basic question is do you want your navigation to match across platforms OR follow what the platform does?

Comment: The application will be developed only for Android, I made a quick demo of what you suggested. The thing is that I would like to keep the top bar as the background of the first card, and this way I do not know if it's okay, because the tabs are not explicitly limited.

[Link to demo](https://imgur.com/FfpWNeb)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to put tabs in the ActionBar, it won't work out well (there isn't much room). You could simply put a typical Tab Bar under the ActionBar, or even remove the ActionBar and just have a Tab Bar at the topmost part of screen (depending on where this screen fits into the greater app lifecycle, that may be suitable).